# Send html format mail stored in variable using sendmail command

Tags: email, sendmail, html

Below script works fine in my Linux server.

```
(
echo "From: name@xyz.com";
echo "To: name2@xyz.com";
echo "Subject: Test Subject";
echo "Content-Type: text/html";
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "";
echo "<html><head><title>HTML E-mail</title></head>
<body><p>Test Body Message</p></body></html>";
) | sendmail -t
```

But after modify the script as below, it shows error as "No recipient address found in header". **Is it possible to workout the below code using variable. I don't want to use any file or any other mail command except sendmail**.

```
var1='(
echo "From: name@xyz.com";
echo "To: name2@xyz.com";
echo "Subject: Test Subject";
echo "Content-Type: text/html";
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "";
echo "<html><head><title>HTML E-mail</title></head>
<body><p>Test Body Message</p></body></html>";
)'

echo ${var1} | sendmail -t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

command substitution will replace end of line by space.

- use `;"` instead of `";`
- use `tr \; '\n'` to renable end of line.
- use awk to de-indent first char as space
- put `To:` line first

this result in somehow ugly

```
var1=$(
echo "To: name2@xyz.com;"
echo "From: name@xyz.com;"
echo "Subject: mail HTML ;"
echo "Content-Type: text/html;"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0;"
echo ";"
echo "<html><head><title>HTML E-mail</title></head>
body><p>Test Body Message</p></body></html>"
)

## can be one-lined, pipe symbol (|) continue line.
echo ${var1} | tr \; '\n' |
awk 'length == 1 || NR == 1 {print $0} length && NR > 1 { print substr($0,2) }'  |
sendmail -t
```

this however my break some html code ( like `&aacute;` turn to `&aacute` ), you know that mail can send attachment  now days  ?

```
man mail
```

> ```
>    -A, --attach=FILE
>           attach FILE
> ```

```
mail -A <(generate HTML result) foo@exemple.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the echo commands from the variable definition.