# Bold a text in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, email, html

I have a sample script here I want to bold the word BOLD in the text and send through email. Tried several ways but not seems to working.

```
BODY="Hello. I want to BOLD this"
{
 echo "From: from@gmail.com"
 echo "To: to@gmail.com"
 echo "Subject: Texting"
 echo "X-Mailer: htmlmail" $VERSION
 echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
 print "<html><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="Geneva,Arial"SIZE=8><body>${BODY} </body>"

print "<html><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="Geneva,Arial"SIZE=10> ${BODY} </html>"
} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Note: shell variables should be lower-case.

Comment: `print` is a ksh/zsh builtin. In bash, use `printf` instead (different interface).

Comment: Since you send the mail in HTML format you have to bracket `BOLD` with HTML tags: `<b>BOLD</b>`.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400858/5132 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you need a blank line between the email header and body.
2. you are trying to put double quotes in a double quoted string, incorrectly.

Try this:

```bsh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t <<END_EMAIL
From: from@example.com
To: to@example.com
Subject: Texting
X-Mailer: htmlmail $version
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII

<html><body><p><b>${BODY}</b></p></body></html>
END_EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

These variables may be of use

```
reset_colour=$(   tput sgr0)
bold=$(           tput bold)
black=$(          tput setaf 0)
red=$(            tput setaf 1)
green=$(          tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(         tput setaf 3)
blue=$(           tput setaf 4)
magenta=$(        tput setaf 5)
cyan=$(           tput setaf 6)
white=$(          tput setaf 7)
default_colour=$( tput setaf 9)
```

Comment: Not in a `text/html` MIME body part, they aren't.  (-:

Comment: Is this question about bash? or e-mail?

Comment: Given that it says "e-mail" in its first sentence and shows the use of the `sendmail` command, one can make an educated guess. (-:

Comment: @JdeBP so the title **Bold a text in Bash**?

Comment: … is something that you should take up with the questioner, in a question comment; is something that one needs to read beyond, to the actual question; and is something that contains no implications of terminal I/O.  (-: